# How do I express "I follow my GPS's instructions"?

Tags: translation

I'm accustomed to sentences like 我听我老公 which literally states "I listen to my husband", but it implies something like "I do what my husband says".  I'm sure I've said 我听你的 to my teacher at some point, implying I'll just follow her advice.

So, when I wanted to express that I do whatever my GPS says, I wrote this:

> 我就听我的GPS

intending to mean

> I follow my GPS's instructions

This was in the context of avoiding getting flustered during traffic jams: following the GPS's instructions helps me relax.  However, my teacher indicated this is a weird thing to say.

If it's relevant, I've somewhat anthropomorphized my GPS, and her name is Lucy.

**Question**: How do I express "I follow my GPS's instructions"?

Maybe a literal translation would be along the lines:

> 我按照我GPS的说明那样开车。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

> 跟着导航走

Short, concise and simple.

- 跟着 = follow
- 导航 = gps
- 走 = go

You could even tell a lost taxi driver the same phrase to let them know to follow the gps.

Answer (score 1):

In this context:

- Follow = 依照 (you are not obeying orders, you are listening to instructions and following them as stated)
- GPS' = 卫星导航的
- guidelines = 指引 (pointing and leading to a specific route)

or

- instructions = 指示 (pointing and showing a specific route)

> Following the GPS' guidelines/ instructions
>
> 依照 卫星导航的 指示
>
> *指示 is the better choice because GPS also shows us maps*

"**Following**" verbal orders is "**听从**"(listen and follow). We don't want to think GPS is giving us orders to obey, right?

Comment: 指引 would be better than 指示, imo. 指示 is more like _order_, _command_. 指引 means _guide_

Answer (score 1):

按导航开; 按照导航来; Even 听导航的; Those are colloquial phrases.

In formal writing,  it could be: 按照GPS导航所指引的路线来行驶.

Answer (score 1):

你刚刚到了纳尼亚。

How on earth did you find this place?
你到底是怎么找到这个地方的？

I just followed the instructions from my Lucy.
我只是按照我的露茜指令。